# DirectoryIndex not working because of mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Requests to www.domainname.com and domainname.com should display index.html, not index.php as it does now.

This is the .htaccess file:

```
# -FrontPage-
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I tried adding a DirectoryIndex index.html to the file, but that did not work. I suspect that has something to do with the mod_rewrite stuff, but being an apache-n00b I am really just grasping for straws.

Can I add a rewriterule, or what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, your .htaccess works fine for me and I get index.html when I request the directory.

You might try inserting this rule:

```
RewriteCond ^/$ /index.html [L]
```

If that doesn't work, get some debug information:

```
RewriteLog "/some/writable/path/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: No, I mean when I copied that .htaccess to my own website.